# How to make a text Bold in Django Administration

Tags: python, django, administration

Is there a way to make a text bold or e.g. bold in Django Administration.

Let's say I have a text field with this Lorum Ipsum text and i want the second word of the sentence to be bold and/or cursive (just like here)[image]:

Lorem ***ipsum*** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Comment: This is not just "Django Administration". Is it flatpages?

Comment: I mean the django admin page

Answer (score 1):

**I think for this you have to take a look at this:-**
https://pypi.org/project/django-markdownfield/

You have to add a markdown field to make text bold.

Comment: hey there thanks a lot for the answer, do you happen to know any other solution like the stars. There should be one, hmm.